# a div class contains onlclick element how handle it in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, onclick

My HTML contains the code below. How do I handle it in Selenium?

```
<div class="node-action" onclick="getNextpage('PageName','ID')">Account Info</div>
```

I have tried with various XPath methods, always getting *"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression"*.

```
WebElement NextPageFind= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@onclick='javascript:getNextpage('PageName','ID');')]"));
NextPageFind.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `span` to `div`

```
WebElement NextPageFind= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@onclick='javascript:getNextpage('PageName','ID');')]"));
```

ie

```
WebElement NextPageFind= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@onclick='javascript:getNextpage('PageName','ID');')]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath can be :

Provision-1:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("node-action")).click();
```

Provision-2:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='node-action' and contains(text(),'Account Info')]")).click();
```

Provision-3:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@onclick='getNextpage('PageName','ID')']")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your xpath to something like what I have below. Changed from a span to a div and tidied up the @onclick string.

The inner string elements of the xpath need to be escaped otherwise it is not interpreted as a valid xpath:

```
WebElement NextPageFind= driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@onclick="getNextpage(\'PageName\',\'ID\')"]'));
```